# How to Invoke method in C#

Tags: c#

From Java I've used the below code to invoke method. Pass the Instance of the class where the method is and then execute.

```
 Context context; //Assuming the passed Instance is initialized here
 Class c = Class.forName(context.getClass().getName()); //Get the class name including it's package and initialized here
 Method m = c.getMethod("thisMethod", String.class, String.class); //Initialize the Method name and it's parameter type
 Object t = c.newInstance();    
 m.invoke(t,"data1", "data2");  //Invoke the method with 2 string
```

I would like to convert the above code in C#. I've tried to search and I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) and it's confused me on how can I use the instance I've passed. so far I have the below code in C#.

```
class Program{
    static InvokerClass ic;
    private static Program programInstance = new Program();

    static void Main(string[] args){
        ic = new InvokerClass(programInstance);
        ic.StartInvokeExample("Hello","World!");
    }

    //Call this method later
    public static void thisMethod(String data1, String data2) {
        Console.WriteLine("DATA1=>" + data1 + ", DATA2=>"+data2);
    }
}

class InvokerClass{

    private Object objInstance;

    public InvokerClass(Object obj){
        this.objInstance = obj; //Get the passed Instance and use this to determine the Class Name
    }

    //Do invoking here
    public void StartInvokeExample(String data1, String data2){

        Type t = Type.GetType("? ? ?"); //I wanted to use the `objInstance` to determine the Class name
        ConstructorInfo cons = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object classObject = cons.Invoke(new object[] { });

        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("thisMethod");
        m.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { data1, data2 });


    }

}
```

From `InvokerClass` I would like to used the `objInstance` to initialize the Class name but I don't know how. And so far I don't know if I'm doing it in proper way.

Comment: Replace `Type t = Type.GetType("? ? ?");` with `Type t = objInstance.GetType()`. Just careful with `objInstance` being `null`

Comment: Instead if searching for the constructor yourself you can just use `Activator.CreateInstance(myType)` to create instances of a type.

Comment: do you think it is reliable to use `if(objInstance !=null){//execute invoke here}`?

Comment: @lopi Definitly. Or even better check if it is null within the constructor of `InvokerClass` and throw an expetion if it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
class InvokerClass
{    
    private Object objInstance;

    public InvokerClass(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj must not be null");
        this.objInstance = obj; //Get the passed Instance and use this to determine the Class Name
    }

    //Do invoking here
    public void StartInvokeExample(String data1, String data2)
    {   
        Type t = objInstance.GetType();
        object classObject = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("thisMethod");
        m.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { data1, data2 });
    }
}
```

Note: you won´t need to get the constructor, simply use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx). Also take care to verify your passed object is not null to avoid a `NullReferenceÈxception` when trying to call `objInstance.GetType()`.

Comment: thank you for answer, is that the better way to do it, I mean the proper?

Comment: Assuming you know the name of the method you are calling and the parameters (as in the example above) is there any reason not to use dynamic typing here?

Comment: By dynamic typing you mean rely on the `dynamic`-keyword? Why would you do this at all? I´d suggest to use it only if you *really* have to, not just because you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the object instance, but I would probably change it to use a generic instead.  Although you are passing in the program object, doing it this way would provide a little more flexibility, because you don't need a an instantiated object to create a new one.  You could also create an overload and get both.  In your example, I would change the methods to static since you don't need an instantiated object in your example.

```
class Program
{
  private static Program programInstance = new Program();

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    InvokerClass.StartInvokeExample<Program>("Hello", "World!");


  }

  public static void thisMethod(String data1, String data2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("DATA1=>" + data1 + ", DATA2=>" + data2);
  }
}

class static InvokerClass
{

  //Do invoking here
  public void StartInvokeExample<T>(String data1, String data2) 
    where T : new()
  {

    Type t = typeof(T); 
    ConstructorInfo cons = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    object classObject = cons.Invoke(new object[] { });

    MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("thisMethod");
    m.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { data1, data2 });


  }

  public static StartInvokeExample
   (Type t, String data1, String data2)
  {
    ConstructorInfo cons = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    object classObject = cons.Invoke(new object[] { });

    MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("thisMethod");
    m.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { data1, data2 });
  }


}
```

Comment: thank you @kevin,  but more info. please? what is the point of changing it to Generic?

Comment: Assumes we know the type to invoke at compile-time. @lopi Do you know what `objInstance` is at *compile-time*?

Comment: OK I get it @kevin, Thank you so much!

Comment: You should consider to add a constraint to your generic to ensure it has a parameterless constructor. Why? Because you *can*, what you can´t (unfortunately) using reflection. Then you won´t need reflection at all, simply call `new T()`.